# Удаление заданного элемента

Tags: javascript, массивы

Может кто-нибудь сказать мне, где ошибка? Я ввожу массив элементов в одно поле, а в другое поле - элемент, который хочу удалить из массива. Мой код не работает.

```
Array.prototype.deleteItem = function(val) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i] === val) {
                this.splice(i, 1);
                i--;
            }
        }
        return this;
    };

    var input = document.getElementById('inputMass').value;
    var del = document.getElementById('deletMass').value;

    function deleteItem () {
    document.writeln(input.deleteItem(del));
    }
```

Comment: А у вас `del` и элементы массива одинакового типа?

Comment: Да, тип одинаковый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение инпута надо превратить в массив:

```js
Array.prototype.deleteItem = function(val) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] === val) {
      this.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return this;
};

function showResult() {
  var input = document.getElementById('inputMass').value.split(',');
  var del = document.getElementById('deletMass').value;

  document.getElementById("result").textContent = input.deleteItem(del);
}
```

```html
<input id='inputMass' value='1,2,3,4' />
<br/>
<input id='deletMass' value='2' />
<br/>

<button onclick="showResult()">Click</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Input я ввожу сам, как и элемент, который необходимо удалить.

Comment: @Andrei Молодец. Это вопрос?

Comment: Да, это вопрос. Возможно неправильно изначально сформировал его (прошу прощения). Массив я ввожу любой (в браузере), как и элемент который хочу удалить с него.

Comment: @Andrei Как Вы вводите массив?

Comment: Имеются два поля input в которые я ввожу в браузере массив. Соответственно в первое поле искомый массив (2, 3, 4, 5...), во второе поле элемент, который хочу удалить (2). По итогу, при нажатии на кнопку rusult я получаю откорректированный массив.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял что было не так сделано.

Comment: @Andrei Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.